# Have any clones married?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, clones

I know that clones were made to fight for the Republic during the Clone Wars, and that's all they were used for. But after Order 66, there wasn't anyone to fight against anymore. So did any clones settle down, maybe even marry afterwards?

Comment: No, they all had short lifespans. I'm guessing they were all dead in a matter of years.

Comment: Cut Lawquane got married but he'd deserted and was mentally ill; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cut_Lawquane

Comment: Canon only or is Legends acceptable?

Comment: @Null Legends is ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In canon, the only clone who got married (that I'm aware of) is [Cut Lawquane](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cut_Lawquane), who deserted and married a Twi'lek named Suu before the Clone Wars ended.

In Legends, there are a few clones who got married.

The most notable is, of course, Boba Fett, who married [Sintas Vel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sintas_Vel) a few years after the Clone Wars (although Boba certainly didn't "settle down" as a result of his marriage). (Obviously, Boba himself is fully canon, but his marriage is present only in Legends.)

All the others I know of are from [Clan Skirata](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Skirata).

- [Fi Skirata](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fi_Skirata) married a human Mandalorian named [Parja Bralor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Parja_Bralor) at the end of the Clone Wars.
- [Null-11 Ordo Skirata](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ordo_Skirata) married a Republic Treasury Audit Division agent named [Besany Wennen](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Besany_Wennen). They married before the Clone Wars ended but survived the war and presumably settled down to live a quiet life.
- Clone commando [Darman Skirata](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darman_Skirata) married a Jedi named [Etain Tur-Mukan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Etain_Tur-Mukan) near the end of the Clone Wars, and they had a son together. However, she was killed shortly after Order 66.

Since we know that *some* clones married it's reasonable to assume that others did as well -- we just don't know much about the clones after the end of the Clone Wars.

Comment: A clone married a Jedi? She must have deserted

Comment: There were married clones in Thrawn trilogy. But I don't think they were clones from the GAR - I think Baron Fel's clones.